# Handling asyncio deadlocks

Tags: python-asyncio

This sample code hangs indefinitely:

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    async def f():
        await g_task

    async def g():
        await f_task

    f_task = asyncio.create_task(f())
    g_task = asyncio.create_task(g())
    await f_task


asyncio.run(main())
```

I'm looking for a way to automatically detect and handle deadlocks, like GoLang does.

So far I came up with a variant of `asyncio.wait_for()`:

[EDIT] overhauled design

https://gist.github.com/gimperiale/549cbad04c24d870145d3f38fbb8e6f0

1 line change in the original code:

```
await wait_check_deadlock(f_task)
```

It works, but with two major problems:

1. it relies on `asyncio.Task._fut_waiter`, which is an implementation detail of CPython
2. The deadlocked tasks will remain in RAM forever. `aw.cancel()` seems to do nothing. If I catch the RecursionError my helper function raises, asyncio.run() raises another RecursionError when it tries cancelling all tasks.

Are there more robust solutions to the problem?

Comment: Side note on golang — it's very much so possible to deadlock a go program. I've done it many times, especially in unit tests that tried to cover corner cases of code that used channels aplenty.

Comment: There's a question if this is in fact a formal deadlock, because Python `asyncio` and `async/await` in general supports cancellation — as long as a reference to `f_task` or `g_task` is available "externally", i.e. to some other co-routine, that other code could call `f_task.cancel()` . Except for that's currently broken: https://bugs.python.org/issue36456  

Comment: Btw., I think you could post your question on https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/async-sig

Answer (score 3):

Deadlock avoidance has been researched a lot, some practical solutions exist, but in general case, the problem is undecidable (I think it can be reduced to the halting problem).

To illustrate practicality, consider this:

```py
await asyncio.sleep(2 ** (1 / random.random()))
```

Depending on your luck, it will either return soon or "practically never".

This trick can be used to show that callback-based program is impossible to predict:

```py
f = asyncio.Future()

async foo():
    await asyncio.sleep(2 ** (1 / random.random()))
    f.set_result(None)

async bar():
    await f

await asyncio.gather(foo(), bar())
```

Likewise, it can be applied to your "pure" async/await program:

```py
async def f():
    await g_task

async def g():
    await asyncio.wait(f_task,
                       asyncio.sleep(2 ** (1 / random.random())),
                       return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

f_task = asyncio.create_task(f())
g_task = asyncio.create_task(g())
await f_task
```

At the same time, imperfect but practical deadlock detector can be very useful, please consider posting your code to core asyncio devs and/or a standalone library.

The current practice is to run tests with `PYTHONASYNCIODEBUG=1` which shows unawaited tasks (destroyed before result / exception was read).

Your library could be better, for example, it could report when some task took longer than X, or when a DAG of tasks depending on given task grows too large.

Comment: I wouldn't consider an overly long sleep as a deadlock - much as I don't consider a web/RPC server to be stuck when there are no clients connected and the server is just waiting on select(). A deadlock is specifically a circular dependency between tasks.

Comment: "Your library could be better, for example, it could report when some task took longer than X" <- I see no reason to reimplement ``wait_for(aw, timeout=...)``

Comment: So true, I should make a clearer distinction between theoretical deadlock `A→B→A` vs. practical deadlock `A→B→race(A, very_long)`

Comment: This sort of "practical" deadlock is trivially detected (at least during testing) by running a custom event loop which doesn't actually wait for time to pass, but merely sets the time to that of the next scheduled coroutine on a `sleep` when idle.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwigBatista would you like to contribute a better answer?

Comment: @DimaTisnek I'd love to be able to, but unfortunately I came across the question because I was searching for it as well. Just thought I'd offer a bit more clarity to anyone else who reaches it, sorry if my tone was impolite.

Comment: As a slightly more actionable point - I have a feeling that stateful testing as present in the library Hypothesis might be useful for detecting possibly deadlocking async code. It's not a theoretical guarantee (the pesky halting problem, as you mentioned), but it could at least catch some mistakes. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to support async code currently, but I'm looking into how that could be implemented.

Comment: I think you have a point. In fact there was a Microsoft research paper where they overrode the OS context switch mechanism to exercise all possible (or as many as possible) permutations, which is like hypothesis / property-based testing for concurrency. The paper is  "Finding and Reproducing Heisenbugs in Concurrent Programs"